# What's the best way to use hamcrest-AS3 to test for membership in an IList?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, hamcrest

I'm using Flex 3.3, with hamcrest-as3 used to test for item membership in a list as part of my unit tests:

```
var myList: IList = new ArrayCollection(['a', 'b', 'c']).list;
assertThat(myList, hasItems('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

The problem is that apparently the `IList` class doesn't support `for each` iteration; for example, with the above list, this will not trace anything:

```
for each (var i: * in myList) { trace (i); }
```

However, tracing either an `Array` or an `ArrayCollection` containing the same data will work just fine.

What I want to do is (without having to tear apart my existing `IList`-based interface) be able to treat an `IList` like an `Array` or an `ArrayCollection` for the purposes of testing, because that's what hamcrest does:

```
override public function matches(collection:Object):Boolean
{
    for each (var item:Object in collection)
    {
        if (_elementMatcher.matches(item))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Is this simply doomed to failure? As a side note, *why* would the IList interface not be amenable to iteration this way? That just seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a custom `Matcher` that's able to iterate over an `IList`. More specifically, extend and override the matches method of `IsArrayContainingMatcher` that you reference above (and you'll probably want to create `IList` specific versions of `hasItem` and `hasItems` as well). A bit of a pain, but perhaps it's worth it to you.

Longer term, you could file an issue with hamcrest-as3 (or fork) to have array iteration abstracted using the Iterator pattern. The right Iterator could then be chosen automatically for the common types (`Proxy`-subclasses, `IList`) with perhaps an optional parameter to supply a custom Iterator.

Answer (score 0):

For the main issue: Instead of passing the ArrayCollection.list to `assertThat()`, pass the ArrayCollection itself. ArrayCollection implements IList and is iterable with `for each`.

```
var myList:IList = new ArrayCollection(['a', 'b', 'c']);
assertThat(myList, hasItems('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

In answer to part two: ArrayCollection.list is an instance of ArrayList which does not extend Proxy and does not implement the required methods in order to iterate with `for each`. ArrayCollection extends ListCollectionView which does extends Proxy and implements the required methods.

HTH.

Comment: It doesn't; I'm using ArrayCollection as an example, but I have another IList implementation that's under test, not an ArrayList.

I'm specifically looking for ways to do this with an IList.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself coming back to this every once in a while. Rather than writing new Matchers, I find that the easiest solution is always to just call toArray() on the IList and match against the resulting array.